# Optimal arrangement with decreasing score

Tags: combinatorics

We are allowed to write numbers $1,2,\ldots,10$ in one of five rows, each number possibly zero or multiple times and even in the same row. After we finish writing, the score of each number is calculated: For each occurrence of the number, if the row contains $a$ numbers, we add $\frac{1}{a-1}$ to the number's score (so if the number is the only one in the row, its score is infinite). Is it true that no matter how we write, some number will have score at most $1$?

It is possible that all numbers have score exactly $1$, if we write each number once and two numbers per row. If we don't write some number, its score is $0$. Writing more than once does not seem to help with this decreasing score function - for example, writing each number twice (so four numbers per row) results in each number receiving a score of only $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$. If we write once per number but do not spread the numbers equally, then the numbers in the row with more than two numbers get a score of less than $1$.

Comment: Hint:  you have to write all the numbers because if you don't there is one with score $0$ and you are done.  If you write them all two per row the score is $1$ for each number, as you say.  Now show that moving a number reduces the total score and writing a new number weakly decreases it.  Conclude that the average score of a number is $1$ or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If five rows contain one element, then there are at least five numbers whose score is zero and we are done. So it suffices to consider the case that there are $k$ rows that do *not* have one element in them, for some $1\le k\le 5$. We consider these $k$ rows only.

Suppose there are $r$ integers in $[1,10]$ whose score is not infinite (so  $r \ge 5+k$). Consider the average score across all the numbers whose score is not infinite. Let $n_i$ be the number of integers in row $i$, for $1\le i\le k$. If $n_i=0$ then row $i$ contributes $0$ to this average; otherwise it contributes $n_i/((n_i-1)r)$ to the average. But this number is at most $2/r \le 2/(5+k)$. Multiplying by $k$, we see that the average is at most $2k/(5+k)$. This is an increasing function of $k$, and its maximum value on the interval $[1,5]$ is $1$, when $k=5$.

Since the greatest average is $1$ and since the minimum is at most the average, we showed that there is always some number with score at most $1$.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is currently wrong because of infinity, which I didn't notice before. I'm working on fixing it.

Comment: The infinity problem should be fixed now.